# pseudocode into R language

Tags: r, pseudocode

I just started using the 'wbs' package and I thought I could get a better sense of it if I code the pseudocode for it in r before I use the package. So, I'm currently turning the wild binary segmentation pseudocode into R programming language material.

```
function WildBinSeg(s, e, ζT) 
    if e−s < 1 then 
        STOP 
    else 
        Ms,e := set of those indices m for which [sm,em] ∈ FM T is such that [sm,em] ⊆ [s,e] 
        (Optional: augment Ms,e := Ms,e ∪{0}, where [s0,e0] = [s,e]) 
        (m0,b0) := argmaxm∈Ms,e,b∈{sm,...,em−1}| ˜ Xb sm,em| 
        if | Xb0 sm0,em0| > ζT then 
            add b0 to the set of estimated change-points 
            WildBinSeg(s, b0, ζT) 
            WildBinSeg(b0 + 1, e, ζT) 
        else 
            STOP 
        end if 
    end if 
end function
```

I got confused at the line:

```
    Ms,e := set of those indices m for which [sm,em] ∈ FM T is such that [sm,em] ⊆ [s,e]
```

I know this is a the pseudocode is a function, but I'm not sure if I should create another function for this line since it has two commands. Can anyone help ne code this line?

Comment: I find your code hard to understand without a definition of `FM T` and `ζT`. There seem to be some characters missing. For me, latex-like subscripts such as `s_m` and `e_{m-1}` or superscripts with `e^{m-1}` would help quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to write a function which would draw M intervals and find maximiser of the absolute value of the CUSUM statistic in each interval (for details see the WBS paper).

In the R code below, I assume that the output of such a function is stored in 'res' variable, which is a 4 by M matrix. The first two columns contain left and right endpoints of the intervals drawn (sm, em), the third one the maximiser of the CUSUM statistic for each interval (bm), the last contains the value of corresponding CUSUM statistic (Xbm sm, em).

```
WildBinSeg <- function(s, e, threshold,res){
    if(e-s <1) return(NULL)
    else{
        #we leave only intervals contained in [s,e]
        res <- res[res[,1]>= s & res[,2]<= e,,drop=FALSE]
        #place for the optional augmentation

        #check if there are any intervals left
        if(nrow(res)==0) return(NULL)
        else{           
            #we find the maximum
            max.id <- which.max(abs(res[,4]))
            b0 <- res[max.id,3]
            Xb0 <- res[max.id,4]

            if(abs(Xb0) > threshold)
                return(c(
                                WildBinSeg(s, b0, threshold,res),
                                b0,
                                WildBinSeg(b0+1,e, threshold,res)
            ))
            else return(NULL)   
        }

    }
}
```

This function returns the localisations of the change-points. You can check how it work using this piece of code.

```
require(wbs)
set.seed(12)
#we generate a piecewise constant function plus Gaussian noise vector
x <- rnorm(1000)
x[1:500] <- x[1:500]+1

res <- wbs(x)$res[,1:4]
#we set the threshold to the recommended value
threshold <- 1.3*sqrt(2*log(1000))



WildBinSeg(1,1000,threshold,res)
```